# Why should I use the spread operator in React Route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am watching a tutorial where instructor uses {...props} inside a route. Why would he use it if he is already passing user and getUser props?:

```
<Route exact path="/user/:login" render={props => (
   <User {...props} getUser={this.getUser} user={user} />
  )}
/>
```

Btw, In the User.js, where those props are being passed to, he uses:
this.props.getUser(this.props.match.params.login). Is it possible it has something to do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would he use it if he is alreading passing user and getUser props?

So that any **other** props get passed like, like `foo` and `bar`.

> In the User.js, where those props are being passed to, he uses: this.props.getUser(this.props.match.params.login). Is it possible it has something to do with this?

No. As you said, he's supplying that prop explicitly, not via spread. And by doing so *after* the spread, he's ensuring that his explicit version is used (it doesn't matter whether you pass a `getUser` to the container's props, it won't get used because his `getUser` overrides it; same with `user`).